# Loading templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

Good day,

I've tried using both **ng-html2js** and **grunt-html2js** to try to load my directive templates as modules when testing but have hit a-bit of a road block on both cases. My questions will revolve around the former as this is what I've attempting to use most.

Correct me if I'm wrong; In order to use **ng-html2js** you must first register the module from node like so:

- **npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor -g**
- This installs it globally which is what I want as I run my karma
  tests using the following command which hands over to the global instance of karma installed.:

  **karma start**
- Next in the **karma.conf.js** file you must then specify which templates you
  want to use and what dependency it is to be used with:

  ```
  preprocessors: {
          'webapp/scripts/*.js': 'coverage',
          'webapp/modules/**/*.js': 'coverage',
          'webapp/modules/groupbydrug.html': 'ng-html2js'
      },
  ```
- When it comes to the test, we can load the module doing this:

  ```
  beforeEach(module('webapp/modules/groupbydrug.html'));
  ```
- Finally we compile as usual, add the directive to a piece of html and test:

  ```
  beforeEach(function () {
      ele = angular.element('<div group-by-drug=""></div>');
      compile(ele)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
  });

  it('should have a table with a class of "drugs-by-mail"', function () {
      var div = ele.find('div.outrepeat');
      console.log(div);
  });
  ```

BTW - The template looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(orderNumber,orderData) in orders" class="drugs-by-mail">
    <table class="recent-order-mail">
    ...
    </table>
   </div>
```

Based on what I've read I should beable to retrieve the **div** from the template but when I try and print it to the console I get an empty object (**Object{}**) when I'd actually expect to see all the content within that div - is that not correct?

So where along here am I going wrong? Or is this an issue with installation (global karma vs local)

Thanks